# Unity3D: Custom UnityEvent AddListener not firing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have my own custom UnityEvent and am trying to add a listener.
I have used `AddListener` on numerous other UI objects, such as buttons, dropdowns, toggles, etc. so I understand the process.  However, when I `Invoke` my UnityEvent, it simply doesn't fire.
I'm receiving no error messages, and after doing reading and research, everything looks correct.  So, not sure what to do further.

This is an object that emits when it's rotated.

This is the basics of my code:

```c#
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Rotator: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public UnityEvent OnRotate;
    int angle = 0;
    int newAngle = 0;

    void Start() 
    {
        OnRotate = new UnityEvent();
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        newAngle = (int)transform.rotation.eulersAngles.z;

        if (newAngle != angle) 
        {
            print ("Actual Instance ID: " + GetInstanceID());
            print ("Invoking!");
            OnRotate.Invoke();
            angle = newAngle;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```c#
public class Owner: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rotator rotator;

    void Start() 
    {
        print ("Rotator Instance ID: " + rotator.GetInstanceID());
        rotator.OnRotate.AddListener(
            () => UpdateRotation()
        );
    }

    void UpdateRotation() 
    {
        print ("Invoked!");
    }
}
```

When the `Rotator` has it's angle changed, I get this in the console:

```c#
Actual Instance ID: 11234
Rotator Instance ID: 11234
Invoking!
```

The instance ID is to make sure I'm working with the same objects and not going in circles for nothing.  They match, so I'm listening to the object that's firing.
However, the listener isn't firing.  I've tried different combinations with delegates, etc. but it's all the same.   No errors.  It just doesn't invoke.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the Rotator was subscribed? Ive not seen someone subscribe to an event like that, does it work if you use += UpdateRotation?

Comment: @BugFinder not for `UnityEvent` there they use `AddListener` and `RemoveListener`.

Comment: It should be a `);` instead of `}` after the `AddListener` block but I guess that's just a typo? Or alternatively simply do `rotator.OnRotate.AddListener(UpdateRotation);`

Comment: @derHugo Correct, they use `AddListener` and `RemoveListener`.  I could try the += but I imagine it accomplishes the same thing.

And yes, that was a typo (otherwise I'd have had a compiler error).  I fixed it.

I did try `rotator.OnRotate.AddListener(UpdateRotation);` and it was the same.

Comment: Strange .. from your code I don't really see a reason why it shouldn't be called .. could you just for trying add a persistent callback via the Inspector just to see if it is invoked at all?

Comment: Also is this all your code or do you maybe anywhere remove listeners / use `OnRotate = new ...` anywhere else which would erase the callback?

Comment: That's my confusion.  I see nothing wrong, and have been using callbacks and listeners for all my other Unity UI elements, so I understand the process.  It just... simply isn't firing.

As far as the Inspector, I added a persistent callback, but as soon as I start the project, it goes blank and says `List is Empty`.  I wasn't sure if I maybe implemented it wrong since I'd never done it before.

Comment: Yes, this is basically it.  There's no where that any listeners are removed, or recreated.  It's very basic.

Comment: Well, made some progress.  
It still doesn't fix the issue, but it might point in the right direction.

If the Rotator is added to the Owner in the inspector, it doesn't work.
However, if the Owner gets the Rotator with:  `rotator = GetComponent<Rotator>();` It does work!

I'm not sure why this would make a difference.  A listener is added to the object, so it should be listening regardless.

Comment: `As far as the Inspector, I added a persistent callback, but as soon as I start the project, it goes blank and says List is Empty` this pretty much sounds like the existing `UnityEvent` is at some point replaced by a new one using `new UnityEvent()` ...

Comment: @derHugo I must admit I am sure I always used +=.. out of interest which version of unity, is it maybe a bug in beta/alpha?

Comment: @BugFinder it is not possible and will throw an exception ..  what you mean is probably something like e.g. `public event Action`. But for [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) afaik it has ever since been `AddListener` and `RemoveListener`. At least until back to `5.4.`

Comment: @derHugo weird - I must be dreaming :D

Answer (score 5):

**Somehow your answered your new edited version of the question with exactly the code you previously provided in the [First Version of your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58306741/1)!**

As I tried to tell you ... if you anywhere in your code do `OnRotate = new UnityEvent()` of course you thereby erase any persistent callbacks and any runtime callbacks added before that moment!

---

**In short**

Simply leave it as

```
public UnityEvent OnRotate;
```

and you don't even have to think about it anymore.

---

For understanding why it also works if you put it in `Awake` please simply have a look at the [Order of Execution for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

→ First `Awake` and `OnEnabled` is called for every GameObject/Component. Then all `Start` methods are called as soon as the GameObject/Component is active.

Within each of these blocks (`Awake` + `OnEnable`) and (`Start`) the order of execution between different component types is not guaranteed unless you explicitly configure it via the [Script Execution Order Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) where you could define that `Owner` is simply run before `Rotator` .. then having both in `Start` would also work again.

---

Why does it also work if you do it on the `public` field?

→ Because this field is **serialized**. That means it is initialized automatically in the Inspector and then stored together with the Scene or prefab asset including any persistent callbacks.

And then Later Unity re-uses the serialized Version of the field so actually you can completely remove the `new UnityEvent();` since it doesn't have any effect on a serialized field! It will always be initialized automatically anyway!

Comment: Thank you for the information and clarification. I knew the order of how they were fired, but public fields being serialized I did _not_ know, that makes a lot of sense!

It was definitely an order of execution issue, and the callback being overwritten.

The reason I edited my original question is because I inadvertently put a working solution when I wrote out my question, since i didn't copy it verbatim.  I had it wrong in my project, and had it right in my question.

I didn't want someone in a future search being confused.  It also better illustrated what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what the issue was.
My question now is "why?".

I changed my code from:

```
public UnityEvent OnRotate;

void Start() {
  OnRotate = new UnityEvent();
}
```

to

```
public UnityEvent OnRotate = new UnityEvent();

void Start() {
}
```

And now it works.

Although, now that I think about it, `Awake()` is the method where they all fire before initialization, whereas `Start()` is when the object is created.  So the `Start()` of the `Rotator` is probably getting called *after* the `Owner` is adding a listener.

Comment: Confirmed.  Changing initialization to `Awake()` worked.

Comment: Please checkout [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331701/7111561)